# Pop!_OS Alt + Tab / Alt + ` or Alt + ~ Behavior

Tags: windows, alt-tab, pop-os

Pop!_OS' feature of switching between apps (and those with multiple instances) has made me productive in some way:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> - switch between different apps
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>~</kbd> - switch between same app(s)

This has significantly reduced the amount of time cycling between a number programs.

I'm looking for something that does the same in Windows. I would not opt for AutoHotKey as it has wreaked havoc with my gaming.

Comment: This is probably better asked in [softwarerecs.se]. In general, questions asking for product or service or learning-material recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?